# Cancancan authorisation of nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, cancancan

I've an Account model which "has many" Users and also "has many" Meters. The Meter object has an account_id column so it's easy to define an ability for this in Cancancan:

```
if user
  can :crud, Meter, :account_id => user.account_id
end
```

However, a Meter also "has many" Parameter. I want to do a similar ability definition, only allowing CRUD access if the parameter belongs to a meter which belongs to the same account as user.

As the Parameter model only has a meter_id column (and not an account_id column), I'm not sure of the best way to achieve this extra level of nesting?

**Edit**

Apologies for being unclear.

My models are as follows:

```
Account > User (account_id) 
        > Meter (account_id) > Parameter (meter_id)
```

So I'm able to check if user.account_id = meter.account_id, but I'm not sure how to check for a parameter.

**Edit 2**

As well as Matt's answer, it's simply a case of including:

```
  load_and_authorize_resource :meter
  load_and_authorize_resource through: :meter
```

in the Parameter model.

Comment: This is not very clear. You mean crud access to `Parameter` models which belong to `Meter` models, which belong to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if user
  can :crud, Parameter, meter: { account_id: user.account_id }
end
```